# How can you define the Abstract styling in Memoir?

Tags: memoir, abstract

According to the manual for the memoir class the following determines the layout of of the abstract.

> The typeset format of an abstract in a report or article class document
>   depends on the class options. The formats are:
>
> - titlepage class option: The abstract heading (i.e., value of \abstractname ) is typeset centered in a bold font; the text is set in
>     the normal font and to the normal width.
> - twocolumn class option: The abstract heading is typeset like an unnumbered section;the text is set in the normal font and to the
>     normal width (of a single column).
> - Default (neither of the above class options): The abstract heading is typeset centered in a small bold font; the text is set in a small  font and indented like the quotation environment.

I would like my abstract to look what is desricbed in the titlepage option but it compiles as a default item. Below is a MWE but when I compile it I get;

> LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):[titlepage]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, titlepage, oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\frontmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way to enforce the titlepage styling option on the abstract?

Comment: As to the specific error, the [memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) states "This class provides neither a titlepage option nor a titlepage environment; instead
it provides the titlingpage environment which falls between the titlepage option and the titlepage environment." (currently on p.65). p.66 shows one example of styling a title page.

Comment: Thanks @MikeRenfro. I was only reading the Manual from chapter 5 about Abstracts which started on Page 69.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description in the manual refers to the shape of the abstract that can be obtained with the standard `article` or `report` classes. It's just an introduction to the subject (thanks to Mike Renfro for having remarked this). I agree with you that it can be misleading.

You have rather to set the parameters `\absleftindent` and `\absrightindent`. You can also do `\abstractintoc` so the abstract will be automatically added to the table of contents.

Use `\tableofcontents*`, or the TOC itself will be listed in the TOC, which is absurd.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % for showing the page boundaries

\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}
\abstractintoc

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The documentation in the question is correct, but it's referring to the standard document classes and their implementation of abstracts ("The typeset format of an abstract *in a report or article class document*"), as a lead-in to memoir's different implementation.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thanks. After rereading the manual I see you're right, but I still think that this has escaped revision, because it could be clearer; maybe moved forward, with examples for emulating in `memoir` the behavior of the standard classes.